# How to uglify javascript "on the go" when the user tries to get .js files (or .php with type-content: javascript)?

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to uglify javascript just as [this](https://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs) tool allows. The thing is I would like to maintain the raw javascript text in the server and avoid minifying duplicated files just to serve them... so my thought process would be something like this:

`1-> user http requests myjavascript.js
 2-> I run it through an uglifier
 3-> I present the javascript code to the user`

I also have javascript with "myjavascript.php" to allow pre-treatment of the file before serving it to the user. (for example, echoing variables to javascript). Any idea on how this could be done using .js and .php files with header(type-content: javascript)? Tyvm for your help...

Comment: You would have to use mod_rewrite to redirect .js urls to a php script that will use the api and return the results.

Comment: Why would you not just pre-compile the uglified version?  What are the drawbacks to doing this? The reality is that static files give you a lot more flexibility in overall application optimization (for example you could put the files into CDN, leverage client-side browser caching, etc.)  Why do you want to expend the computational power (and application response time) to generate each js file for every request?  Conversely, what is the downside to generating a minified js file that is never used? It likely only occupies a few KB of storage space and storage is cheap.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

If using Apache, you could install [mod_pagespeed](http://modpagespeed.com/) (an open-source Apache module created by Google to help Make the Web Faster by rewriting web pages to reduce latency and bandwidth) with its `rewrite_javascript` option.

**Solution 2**

Use a CDN which offers minification options such as [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) with its [AutoMinify](https://blog.cloudflare.com/an-all-new-and-improved-autominify/) option.

Answer (score -1):

Its not good solution. Depends on your js file size, it can be painfull for your server. Best way is to use some uglify php script to generate new files. Original files just put to the non public folder. I.e:

```
/application 
/scripts 
/public
    /js/ {dynamic content / cache}
    /index.php
```

Inside scripts you put original files. You can clear cache manualy or by cron, using some special address and generating new js files. If you want automatic way, you can always check modify date of your scripts and generate new one if changed - slower, but still better way than generating scripts everytime